# Using Sub-queries in HQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, subquery, hql

I have following SQL query from which I need to from the valid HQL query

```
  Select   Temp.*,
    (select
       case 
        when count(tab7.id)>0 then 1 
        else 0 
       end 
      from
       table7 tab7 
      where
       tab7.id = Temp.col_3_0_ 
       ) As Col_6_0_  
       from (Select
      tab5.col1 As Col_0_0_,
      tab5.col2 As Col_1_0_,
      sum(tab5.col3) as col_2_0_,
      tab5.col4 as col_3_0_,
     from

      table5 tab5,
       table1 tab1
  table2 tab2
  where
    tab2.somecol=tab5.somecol 
      and tab1.id=tab5.id 
     GROUP BY  tab5.col1    ,
      tab5.col2                 ,
       tab5.col4   ) Temp
```

But i am facing the Syntax issues when i am trying to execute the HQL query in this way.

**Questions:**

1. Is there any way to use the subqueries in `from` cluase in HQL?
2. If not, how can i achieve this in hibernate?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use detached criteria to fire a subquery or in query in criteria in hibernate

below is sample code for you

`Criteria cr = getSession().createCriteria(Payment.class, "P");
cr.add(Subqueries.propertyNotIn("P.paymentId",DetachedCriteria.forClass(Refund.class, "refund")
.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq("refund.isCancelled", false), 
Restrictions.isNull("refund.isCancelled")))
.setProjection(Property.forName("refund.payment.paymentId"))))`

cheers

Comment: And how the `GROUP BY` will be formed here, including the sum of the inner subquery column(`tab5.col3`)

Comment: Arun if there is sum in inner query than there is no meaning of group by